# How to write contents of a file to new file removing repeated lines

Tags: linux, command-line, files, vi

For example, a file `file1.txt` contains

```
Hi how are you  
hello  
today is monday  
hello  
I am fine  
Hi how are you
```

After the processing of `file1.txt` it should write to `file2.txt` and contents should be like this without repeating the same lines.

```
Hi how are you  
hello  
today is monday  
I am fine
```

What command can I use to do that in linux terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an easy job for `sort`, use the unique (`-u`) option of `sort`:

```
% sort -u file1.txt
hello
Hi how are you
I am fine
today is monday
```

To save it in `file2.txt`:

```
sort -u file1.txt >file2.txt
```

---

If you want to preserve the initial order:

```
% nl file1.txt | sort -uk2,2 | sort -k1,1n | cut -f2
Hi how are you
hello
today is monday
I am fine
```

Comment: Not sure how this is marked as correct as the output shown in the answer does not match the OPs request.

Comment: @IanW Fixed....

Answer (score 6):

```
start cmd:> awk 'lines[$0]++ == 0' input
Hi how are you
hello  
today is monday  
I am fine
```

Comment: @Rmano Not my achievement, though; seen here before... ;-)  (easier to reproduce than to find the other question).